# Combining select and select distinct in Join

Tags: sql, select, join, distinct

I have 2 tables which can be linked with a key. The problem is that 1 table is also time sliced. I only need 2 rows from this table, but they get repeated a lot for different times. So I want to do a select distinct value from this table and link it to my other one.
What I try to do:

```
SELECT a.firstcolumn,
       a.secondcolumn,
       b.somecolumn
from table1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT somecolumn from table2) b
    on a.key = b.key
```

This code runs but I get too much records (almost twice as much) so the distinct isn't doing its job somehow.
I want the output to contain a.firstcolumn, a.secondcolumn and b.somecolumn

Comment: Since you don't select any table2 column you can use EXISTS instead of JOIN.

Comment: if you just want to 2 rows,then why not try LIMIT ?

Comment: @jarlh . . . The OP clarified that a column from b is in the output, so I added it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, then EXISTS can't be used.

Comment: Yes I do want an output from the second table. I found something that works but that doesn't give me output of the second table which I need. What works: 
Select
 a.firstcolumn
b.firstcolumn
from table1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT key from table2) b
on a.key = b.key


How can I add b.somecolumn to the output?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  If you have a time-sliced table, the purpose is to have a date/time for choosing the value.  Often the most recent value is one where the `end_dt` (for lack of better term) is far in the future or `NULL`.

Without knowing your data structure, I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT a.firstcolumn, a.secondcolumn, b.somecolumn
FROM table1 a JOIN 
     b 
     ON a.key = b.key AND b.end_dt IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but I cant trust the data column to be filled in well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dropping the distinct and taking the max (or min) of the date field would give you what you need.

```
SELECT a.firstcolumn,
       a.secondcolumn,
       b.somecolumn
from table1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT key, somecolumn, max(date) from table2 group by key, somecolumn) b
    on a.key = b.key
```

Comment: That would work if the date field would be filled in correctly. also i have DATETO = "99991231" or DATETO = "18991231" which could be duplicates also.

Comment: @GertKnoops I think it would still work even if the dates are incorrect. As long as the field is a date or numeric datatype, it will take only the max or min. Since you're discarding the data in your final output, it won't matter if a record with invalid date is used.